# How to access create-react-app run in a docker container?

Tags: reactjs, docker

I followed the steps under https://mherman.org/blog/dockerizing-a-react-app/

My setup:

- Windows 10 Home
- docker commands are run in the Docker Quickstart Terminal https://docs.docker.com/toolbox/toolbox_install_windows/

How to reproduce: Follow the steps from the first link:

install create-react-app globally:

```
npm install -g create-react-app@3.4.1
```

Generate new app:

```
$ npm init react-app sample --use-npm
$ cd sample
```

Create Dockerfile in the root of directory:

```
# pull official base image
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent

# add app
COPY . ./

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Add .dockerignore:

```
node_modules
build
.dockerignore
Dockerfile
Dockerfile.prod
```

Build and tag the dockerimage:

```
$ docker build -t sample:dev .
```

Spin up the container:

```
$ docker run \
    -it \
    --rm \
    -v ${PWD}:/app \
    -v /app/node_modules \
    -p 3001:3000 \
    -e CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true \
    sample:dev
```

This is what I see in the Docker Quickstart Terminal:
[image]

And this is my project structure:
[image]

However, when I go to localhost:3001 as described in the post, I see 
[image]

Any idea where I'm missing something?

Comment: If you're using Docker Toolbox, you need to point your browser at the `docker-machine ip` address (often 192.168.99.100); `localhost` won't work.

Comment: @DavidMaze thanks, I wasn't aware that this might cause a problem. However, when I point to that address (it is indeed the one you named), there's still the result from above. Can i somehow specify the application?

Comment: I solved it by upgrading to Windows 10 Pro and using Docker Desktop... Can't help you any further with that I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the container, specify the port like this: `3000:80` (use :80)

```sh
$ docker run -it --rm -p 3000:80 sample:prod
```

You can then navigate to http://localhost:3000/ to see the CRA app.

Comment: The result stays the same, thanks for your answer nevertheless.